# Can I refresh SQLite data index(_id) after delete a row?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table and inserted 5 rows,

```
1  testsql 3456 
2  tese weqe 
3  testdfs sfd 
4  testsfssql 3sf6 
5  tese weqe
```

When I delete _id=4, the database becomes

```
1  testsql 3456 
2  tese weqe 
3  testdfs sfd 
5  tese weqe
```

Can I refresh SQLite data index(_id) to

```
1  testsql 3456 
2  tese weqe 
3  testdfs sfd 
4  tese weqe
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Can I refresh SQLite data index(_id)." If you mean changing the index of all rows above 4, sure, you can do that with an `UPDATE` query, though it's not a good idea. Also, please pay attention to the formatting of your post. The original formatting was unintelligible.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. When do you ever need to query by the `_id`, which would hopefully be an auto-increment field?

Answer (score 0):

Completely useless but you can do it (using your example where you delete _id=4)

```
UPDATE table SET _id = _id - 1 WHERE _id > 4;
```

Comment: This fails if there is any duplicate in the middle of the execution.